# RecyclerView is duplicating items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

My recyclerview is duplicating items when I roll it and I'm already calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

So, probably I'm calling data set update at wrong place, but I can't find how it works.

Here is some code:

```
       RecyclerView packageRecyclerView;
        Intent intent;
        ChecklistAdapter recyclerViewAdapter;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_checklist);
    
            intent = getIntent();
            size = intent.getIntExtra("size", 0);
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate - Qtd Questões: " + size);
    
            packageRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.package_lst);
    
            LinearLayoutManager recyclerLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
            packageRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(recyclerLayoutManager);
    
            DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration =
                    new DividerItemDecoration(packageRecyclerView.getContext(),
                            recyclerLayoutManager.getOrientation());
            packageRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
    
            List<Checklist> modelList = new ArrayList<>();
            recyclerViewAdapter = new ChecklistAdapter(modelList,this);
            modelList = getPackages();
            recyclerViewAdapter = new ChecklistAdapter(modelList,this);
    
    //        recyclerViewAdapter = new ChecklistAdapter(getPackages(),this);
    
            packageRecyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
    
    
        }
    
        private List<Checklist> getPackages() {
            List<Checklist> modelList = new ArrayList<>();
            Log.d(TAG, "getPackages: " + size);
            for (int i=0; i<size;i++) {
    
                List<String> priceList = new ArrayList<>();
                priceList.add("Sim");
                priceList.add("Não");
                priceList.add("Não se Aplica");
                modelList.add(new Checklist(intent.getStringExtra("q"+i), priceList));
            }
    
            recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return modelList;
        }
```

Here is my adapter:

```
    public class ChecklistAdapter extends
        RecyclerView.Adapter<ChecklistAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<Checklist> packageList;
    private Context context;

    public ChecklistAdapter(List<Checklist> packageListIn
            , Context ctx) {
        packageList = packageListIn;
        context = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return super.getItemViewType(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void setHasStableIds(boolean hasStableIds) {
        super.setHasStableIds(hasStableIds);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return super.getItemId(position);
    }

    @Override
    public ChecklistAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                                    int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.rv_checklistlines, parent, false);

        ChecklistAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder =
                new ChecklistAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull List<Object> payloads) {
        super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position, payloads);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ChecklistAdapter.ViewHolder holder,
                                 int position) {
        Checklist packageModel = packageList.get(position);
        holder.packageName.setText(packageModel.getTitle());

        int id = (position+1)*100;
        for(String price : packageModel.getQuestions()){
            RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(ChecklistAdapter.this.context);
            rb.setId(id++);
            rb.setText(price);

            holder.priceGroup.addView(rb);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return packageList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView packageName;
        public RadioGroup priceGroup;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            packageName = view.findViewById(R.id.package_name);
            priceGroup = view.findViewById(R.id.price_grp);

            priceGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {

                    Toast.makeText(ChecklistAdapter.this.context,
                            "Radio button clicked " + radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

In the image below you can see that radio buttons are duplicated and there is some extra blank space in all rows. I saw many questions here and in another forums about this, but it's not clear to me where to call this update dataset.

[image]

I'm not an advanced Android developer, so if you can explain, it will be easier to me.

**EDIT 1**

Checklist class:

```
       import java.util.List;
    
    public class Checklist {
    
        String title;
        List<String> questions;
    
        public Checklist(String title, List<String> questions) {
            this.title = title;
            this.questions = questions;
        }
    
        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }
    
        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }
    
        public List<String> getQuestions() {
            return questions;
        }
    
        public void setQuestions(List<String> questions) {
            this.questions = questions;
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Adapter Code updated

Comment: set `priceList` and `modelList`as global, move  `modelList.add(new Checklist(intent.getStringExtra("q"+i), priceList));` outside for loop and try

Comment: @JohnJoe this way I got only one question and only 3 radio buttons. I want all the questions (image 5.10, 5.11, 5.12 and more) with 3 radio buttons for each question.

Comment: post your checkList code

Comment: @JohnJoe edited

Comment: @Alan, You should use this method _recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();_ after `setAdapter`

Comment: @RakeshKumar I've tried it without success.

Comment: @Alan any joy with my answer?

Comment: @Alan Is that repeated only once or multiple times when you scroll?

Comment: @Alan did you make sure to take out the second `recyclerViewAdapter = new ChecklistAdapter(modelList,this);` when trying @Rakesh Kumar suggestion?

Comment: @Alan, You do not need call `recyclerViewAdapter = new ChecklistAdapter(modelList,this);` twice

Comment: @RakeshKumar I know, it was just a test.

Comment: @Alan, Did you check the list size on Adapter `packageList = packageListIn;`?? Are you getting the same???

Comment: best solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70385937/recycler-view-with-duplicate-rows-after-refreshing-activity

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I replicated your problem.

adding `holder.priceGroup.removeAllViews();` on `onBindViewHolder` will fix it. Like so:

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ChecklistAdapter.ViewHolder holder,
                             int position) {
    Checklist packageModel = packageList.get(position);
    holder.packageName.setText(packageModel.getTitle());

    int id = (position+1)*100;
    holder.priceGroup.removeAllViews();

    for(String price : packageModel.getQuestions()){
        RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(ChecklistAdapter.this.context);
        rb.setId(id++);
        rb.setText(price);
        holder.priceGroup.addView(rb);
    }
}
```

You were adding to the view every time without removing the previous views.

Comment: Awesome. It works. I also removed setHasStableIds and getItemViewType, maybe it can help someone else. Thx all for your time.

Comment: No bother, I didn't even include them when I copied your code, just used the original.

Comment: Just realized one more thing, it do not duplicates anymore, but it loses selected radios when I scroll.

Comment: radios you clicked say on question 3? and you scroll down to say question 25, and then return to question 3? and it is unchecked? Is that the problem?

Comment: Yes, thats the problem.

Comment: i understand actually, the views get destroyed every time you scroll, you will need to store this data and retrieve it when ever you return and set it when you return to the view.

Comment: See the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32255720/recyclerview-adapter-resets-radio-buttons)

Comment: One more time helped me.

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU!!!!. I have similar problem, because i was adding views to parent as recyclerview. The data got duplicated after adding new data / scrolling, now I know why, thanks!!!!

Answer (score 14):

Use   `holder.setIsRecyclable(false)` in  `onCreateViewHolder()`

It worked for me.

Comment: This helped to solve the issue with ViewPager2 and recycler adapter with multiple view types

Comment: This will violate the real use case of recycler view.

Answer (score 6):

You just need to call `list.clear();` before insert into `RecyclerViewAdapter`. then call after call `adapter.notifyDatasetChange()`

Comment: Please don't share image of code instead of code snipet.

Answer (score 4):

you have to setHasStableIds(true) to your Adapter in your activity.

and in your Adapter class you have to set below method. It may help you. it is work for me.

```
  @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    @Override
    public void setHasStableIds(boolean hasStableIds) {
        super.setHasStableIds(hasStableIds);
    }
```

you want like this?

[image]

Comment: it is repeating all items now, not only radios.

Comment: I did it as you said. I want exactly what you show at your picture, but with only 3 radios for each question. With your code its duplicating.

Answer (score 4):

Put holder.setIsRecyclable(false) in onBindViewHolder() like below example.

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(UsageStatVH holder, int position) {
        holder.bindTo(list.get(position));
        holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Please override the below method in ChecklistAdapter

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

And in in your onCreate() add:

```
recyclerViewAdapter.setHasStableIds(true);
```

Comment: I got an error: Cannot change whether this adapter has stable IDs while the adapter has registered observers.

Comment: @Alan You must use recyclerViewAdapter.setHasStableIds(true); before packageRecyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);

Comment: @Alan https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52460141/cannot-change-whether-this-adapter-has-stable-ids-while-the-adapter-has-register hope this could help you

Comment: It do not duplicate radios anymore, but it is reording items and radios, so I can't get the responses.

Comment: @Alan do you override getItemViewType() in the adapter?

Comment: remember you're commenting out the block of code that modifies lastCheckedRadioGroup

Comment: you don't need to have getItemViewType() in your adapter since you have only 1 type of items in it; so please remove it

Comment: replace return super.getItemId(position); wtih just return position;

Comment: With this change, it returned giving me 6 radios.

Comment: @Alan check my new answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are setting your list three time to adapter,

At this time i can't write whole code, but replace this block in your code it will work.

Try this code,

```
    DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(packageRecyclerView.getContext(), recyclerLayoutManager.getOrientation()); 
    packageRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
    List<Checklist> modelList = new ArrayList<>(); 
    modelList = getPackages(); recyclerViewAdapter = new ChecklistAdapter(modelList,this);  
    packageRecyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
```

And also remove below line from your getPackages() function.

```
recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Still the same thing, when I scroll, items duplicate.

Comment: You are making modelList in for loop, remove it from for loop and add data only once.

Comment: modelList is created before for loop, I'm just adding items to it inside for loop.

Comment: Yes, that is the problem, you are adding data in loop so you list will contain same data for three time.

Comment: Take a look at the image, in the loop I'm adding one title (image question) and 3 radio buttons to each question. When I scroll it duplicates to six radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

**Instead of**

```
 List<Checklist> modelList = new ArrayList<>();
    recyclerViewAdapter = new ChecklistAdapter(modelList,this);
    modelList = getPackages();
    recyclerViewAdapter = new ChecklistAdapter(modelList,this);
    packageRecyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
```

**Use like this**

```
    recyclerViewAdapter = new ChecklistAdapter(getPackages(),this);
    packageRecyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
```

**AND modify your getPackages method like**

```
private List<Checklist> getPackages() {
 List<Checklist> modelList = new ArrayList<>();
 Log.d(TAG, "getPackages: " + size);

for (int i=0; i<size;i++) {
   List<String> priceList = new ArrayList<>();
    priceList.add("Sim");
    priceList.add("Não");
    priceList.add("Não se Aplica");
    modelList.add(new Checklist(intent.getStringExtra("q"+i), priceList));
}
return modelList;
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @Alan if your item duplicate when you scrolled then it's problem within your **onBindViewHolder** when you add radio button in a radio group.
**It's because of every time you scrolled, your onBindViewHolder method call and adding new radio button**

Comment: Can you explain more, please? Your answer do not solved the problem.

Comment: @Alan I added another answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Modify your Checklist...**

```
public class Checklist {

    String title;
    List<String> questions;
    boolean isRadioButtonAdded;

    public Checklist(String title, List<String> questions) {
        this.title = title;
        this.questions = questions;
    }
    public boolean getIsAdded(){
        return isRadioButtonAdded;
    }
    
    public void setIsAdded(boolean isAdded){
        this.isRadioButtonAdded = isAdded;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public List<String> getQuestions() {
        return questions;
    }

    public void setQuestions(List<String> questions) {
        this.questions = questions;
}
```

**And modify your onBindViewHolder**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ChecklistAdapter.ViewHolder holder,
                             int position) {
    Checklist packageModel = packageList.get(position);
    holder.packageName.setText(packageModel.getTitle());

    int id = (position+1)*100;
    if(!packageModel.getIsAdded){
        for(String price : packageModel.getQuestions()){
            RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(ChecklistAdapter.this.context);
            rb.setId(id++);
            rb.setText(price);

            holder.priceGroup.addView(rb);
            packageModel.setIsAdded(true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: List stills repeating. :(

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with **DiffUtils** I had same problem making duplicate item while i tried to get list from **Room DB** then updating **Recyclerview**

before

```
private fun getLocalMessage(offset: Int, scrollToEnd: Boolean) {
    vm.getLocalMessage(channelId = channelId, offset = offset) {
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            val job = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                channelMessageDB.addAll(it)
            }
            job.join()
            bindMessagesToRv(messageList = channelMessageDB, enableScrollToEnd = scrollToEnd)
        }
    }
}

private fun bindMessagesToRv(
    message: ChannelMessageEntity.ChannelMessageData? = null,
    messageList: List<ChannelMessageEntity.ChannelMessageData> = emptyList(),
    enableScrollToEnd: Boolean = false
) {
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        if (messageList.isNotEmpty()) {
            val job = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                channelMessage.addAll(messageList)
            }
            job.join()
            channelMessage.sortedBy {
                it.messageTime
            }.apply {
                adapter.addItem(newItem = this)
            }

        }
        message?.let {
            channelMessage.add(it)
            adapter.addItem(newItem = channelMessage)

        }

    }
}
```

Then I update my localmessage function to this

```
private fun getLocalMessage(offset: Int, scrollToEnd: Boolean) {
    vm.getLocalMessage(channelId = channelId, offset = offset) {
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            bindMessagesToRv(messageList = it, enableScrollToEnd = scrollToEnd)
        }
    }
}
```

already I had two list which I pass them , now just one . Might help , GL :)