# RecyclerView is duplicating items What might be possible solution?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, geofire

```
RecyclerView r1;
LocationCallback callback;
Location location;
FusedLocationProviderClient client;
public String name, car, number;
ArrayList<MyModel> list = new ArrayList<>();
Boolean flag = false;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recycler);
    r1 = findViewById(R.id.r1);
    client = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    callback = new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(@NonNull LocationResult locationResult) {
            super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
            if (locationResult == null) {
                return;
            }
            location = locationResult.getLastLocation();

            getdriver();

            Toast.makeText(Recycler.this, "Location is:" + location.getLongitude() + location.getLatitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
    showupadatelocation();
}
private void showupadatelocation() {
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) && locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
        LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(4000)
                .setFastestInterval(3000);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        client.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, callback, Looper.myLooper());
    } else {
        startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
    }
}
MyAdapter myAdapter;
private void getdriver() {
    DatabaseReference driver = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Drivers Available");
    GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(driver);
    GeoQuery geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 100);
    geoQuery.removeAllListeners();
    geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {
            DatabaseReference reff = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Drivers").child(key);
            reff.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.exists()) {
                        flag = true;
                        Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) snapshot.getValue();
                        if (map.get("Name") != null) {
                            name = map.get("Name").toString();
                        }
                        if (map.get("Number") != null) {
                            number = map.get("Number").toString();
                        }
                        if (map.get("Car") != null) {
                            car = map.get("Car").toString();
                        }
                        list.add(new MyModel(name,number,car));
                        /*
                        int count=list.size();
                        int count1=myAdapter.getItemCount();
                        if(count==count1){
                            list.add(new MyModel(name,number,car));
                            flag=true;
                        }
                    Toast.makeText(Recycler.this, "list size"+count, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Toast.makeText(Recycler.this, "Adapter size"+count1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                         */
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                }
            });
        }
        @Override
        public void onKeyExited(String key) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onKeyMoved(String key, GeoLocation location) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onGeoQueryReady() {

        }
        @Override
        public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
    myAdapter = new MyAdapter(list, Recycler.this);
    r1.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    r1.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(Recycler.this));
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    list.clear();
    client.removeLocationUpdates(callback);
}
```

Here is my Adapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.viewholder> {
ArrayList <MyModel> list;
Context context;
public MyAdapter(ArrayList<MyModel> list, Context context) {
    this.list = list;
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public viewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.driverinfo,parent,false);
    return new viewholder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull viewholder holder, int position) {
    MyModel myModel=list.get(position);
    holder.t1.setText(myModel.getName());
    holder.t2.setText(myModel.getNumber());
    holder.t3.setText(myModel.getCar());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}
public class viewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView t1,t2,t3;
    public viewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        t1=itemView.findViewById(R.id.namber);
        t2=itemView.findViewById(R.id.naame);
        t3=itemView.findViewById(R.id.caar);
    }
}
```

Here is the duplication of data  in RecyclerView Although i've only 2 details in my firebase database

[This is the structure of my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJfBP.png)

[And this is what my problem is the recycler view keeps on adding data in an infinite loop what might be the condition for stopping this to happen ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHRwo.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried to have [stable Ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54819214/recyclerview-is-duplicating-items/54820003#54820003)?

Comment: Have you tried to clear the list before adding new data?

Comment: @Zain I've not tried stable Id's what is that can you please elaborate to me in detail?

Comment: It gives a unique id to each recyclerView item so that it makes sure not to show duplicate items that have the same id

Comment: @AlexMamo Yes, I tried to clear the list before adding the new details but I was facing some Irrelative Issues in that whenever i was having 2 data in  my database the list size was getting double, for example data 2, size  was 4 i don't know why was happening that otherwise i had a logic to stop the duplication of data but Maybe i was clearing the data not in the beginning but in middle of the code, I'll try to clear the list in the beginning of the program and will let you know if that works!

Comment: @Zain oh that's the great idea but where do i have to write that line of code in my program ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
geoQuery.getCache().clear();
```

Comment: it shows that there is no such kind of function geoQuery.getCache().clear(); it shows error in getCache()